# Angular mat-table with inline editing. Issues with data binding between fields within a row

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a mat-table which has two columns, the first column is a "text" input field (input type="text" and the second column is a hidden field (input type="hidden") who's value is bound to the input field.

In my table cell template, for any column that contains a hidden field, I have an ng-container that is inserted next to the hidden field that is set to display the value data[column] of the input field for that column (the "value" of the hidden field).

When I update the text input in the first column, I can see from the chrome elements inspector that the hidden field's value is in fact bound to the text input and updates to reflect whatever text is inside the text field.

However, the ng-container content does not update in real time. It only updates to reflect the value of the text input after I add a new row to the table (via an addRow method).

Here is the table cell template code (scroll to "STACKOVERFLOW" comment to find the ng-container I'm referring to):

```
<table
  #table
  mat-table
  matSort
  matSortDisableClear
  (matSortChange)="sortData($event)"
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  >
  <!--
    NOTE - Don' use on mat-table. Causing inconsistent updates when add, delete, move... Instead, use below on *ngFor.
    [trackBy]="trackByData"
  -->
  <!--
    NOTE - trackByData does not account for logic-changed properties changes like readonly, disabled, or required
    ng-container... trackBy: trackByData;
  -->
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of tableConfig?.columns; index as i; trackBy: trackByData" matColumnDef="{{column}}">

    <ng-container>
      <th mat-header-cell
        mat-sort-header
        [disabled]="sortDisabled || [SELECTION_COLUMN_NAME, ACTIONS_COLUMN_NAME].includes(column)"
        [ngClass]="{'hidden-column': tableConfig?.hiddenColumns.includes(column)}"
        *matHeaderCellDef>
        <ng-container *ngIf="column === SELECTION_COLUMN_NAME && options?.rowSelection && editable">
          <!-- Selection Column -->
          <mat-checkbox fisStyle
                      [aria-label]="isAllSelected ? 'Select' : 'Unselect' +  'all'"
                      [checked]="masterToggleChecked"
                      [color]="'primary'"
                      [indeterminate]="masterToggleIndeterminate"
                      (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null">
          </mat-checkbox>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="column === ACTIONS_COLUMN_NAME && _hasRowAction">
          <!-- Action Column -->
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="![SELECTION_COLUMN_NAME, ACTIONS_COLUMN_NAME].includes(column)">
          <!-- Standard Column(s) -->
          {{ 'myForms.' + ((tableConfig?.columnNames || [])[column] || (column | startCase)) | myTranslate | async  }}
        </ng-container>
      </th>
      <!-- STACKOVERFLOW EXAMPLE CODE HERE-->
      <td mat-cell
        [ngClass]="{'hidden-column': tableConfig?.hiddenColumns.includes(column)}"
        *matCellDef="let data; let rowIndex = index">

        <!--THIS IS THE CONTAINER THAT DOES NOT UPDATE IN REAL TIME AS EXPECTED. DATA IS NOT UPDATED UNTIL ADDROW METHOD CALLED-->
        <ng-container *ngIf="!['builder'].includes(mode) && tableConfig?.columnTypes[column] === 'default'">{{ data[column] }}</ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="column !== ACTIONS_COLUMN_NAME">
          <div *ngIf="layout[i] && layout[i].widget"
          [class.cell-hidden]="(getFormArrayControlsSafely[rowIndex + paginationRowOffset]?.controls[column]?.hidden | async) || false">
            <drag-drop-menu *ngIf="dragDropEnhancedMode" #menu class="no-display-inline no-display-tooltip" [item]="childTemplateModel[i]"></drag-drop-menu>
            <select-widget-widget
              [class]="dragDropEnhancedMode && childTemplateModel ? getActiveItemClass(childTemplateModel[i]) : ''"
              (change)="onCellChange($event, rowIndex, column)"
              [logic]="layout[i]?.options?.logic || {}"
              [rowIndex]="rowIndex + paginationRowOffset"
              [dataIndex]="[].concat(rowIndex + paginationRowOffset)"
              [layoutIndex]="(layoutIndex || []).concat(i)"
              [layoutNode]="layout[i]">
            </select-widget-widget>
          </div>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="column === ACTIONS_COLUMN_NAME && _hasRowAction && editable">
          <ng-container *ngIf="dragDropEnhancedMode">
            <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Row Actions" (click)="$event.preventDefault()"><mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon></button>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container *ngIf="!dragDropEnhancedMode">
            <button mat-icon-button
              [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
              aria-label="Row Actions"
              (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
              <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="my-data-table">
              <button *ngIf="options?.editRow"
                mat-menu-item
                [disabled]="true"
                (click)="editRow($event, rowIndex + paginationRowOffset)">
                <mat-icon color="inherit">edit</mat-icon>
                <span [innerHTML]="'myForms.Edit'| myTranslate | async"></span>
              </button>

              <mat-divider *ngIf="options?.editRow && options?.deleteRow"></mat-divider>

              <button *ngIf="options?.deleteRow"
                mat-menu-item
                [disabled]="filterInProgress"
                (click)="deleteRow($event, rowIndex + paginationRowOffset)">
                <mat-icon color="inherit">delete</mat-icon>
                <span [innerHTML]="'myForms.Delete'| myTranslate | async"></span>
              </button>

              <mat-divider *ngIf="options?.moveRow && (options?.deleteRow || options?.editRow)"></mat-divider>

              <button *ngIf="options?.moveRow"
                mat-menu-item
                [disabled]="filterInProgress || rowIndex + paginationRowOffset === 0"
                (click)="moveFirstRow($event, rowIndex + paginationRowOffset)">
                <mat-icon class="rotate-90" color="inherit">first_page</mat-icon>
                <span [innerHTML]="'myForms.Move First'| myTranslate | async"></span>
              </button>

              <button *ngIf="options?.moveRow"
                mat-menu-item
                [disabled]="filterInProgress || rowIndex + paginationRowOffset === 0"
                (click)="moveUpRow($event, rowIndex + paginationRowOffset)">
                <mat-icon color="inherit">expand_less</mat-icon>
                <span [innerHTML]="'myForms.Move Up'| myTranslate | async"></span>
              </button>

              <button *ngIf="options?.moveRow"
                mat-menu-item
                [disabled]="filterInProgress || rowIndex + paginationRowOffset === totalRows - 1"
                (click)="moveDownRow($event, rowIndex + paginationRowOffset)">
                <mat-icon color="inherit">expand_more</mat-icon>
                <span></span>
                <span [innerHTML]="'myForms.Move Down'| myTranslate | async"></span>
              </button>

              <button *ngIf="options?.moveRow"
                mat-menu-item
                [disabled]="filterInProgress || rowIndex + paginationRowOffset === totalRows - 1"
                (click)="moveLastRow($event, rowIndex + paginationRowOffset)">
                <mat-icon class="rotate-90" color="inherit">last_page</mat-icon>
                <span></span>
                <span [innerHTML]="'myForms.Move Last'| myTranslate | async"></span>
              </button>
            </mat-menu>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>

      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Footer Column -->
    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> {{ column | tableColumnTotal : column :footerTotalsDatasource : tableConfig }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableConfig?.columns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableConfig?.columns;"></tr>
  <ng-container *ngIf="options?.footerRow">
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="tableConfig?.columns"></tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Here is the ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit() {

this.componentId = JsonSchemaFormService.GetUniqueId();
this.options = cloneDeep(this.layoutNode.options) || {};

this.options.filterEnable = ENABLE_FILTERING && this.options.filterEnable;
this.options.paginationEnable = ENABLE_PAGINATION && this.options.paginationEnable;
this.options.sortingEnable = ENABLE_SORTING && this.options.sortingEnable;


this.jsf.initializeControl(this);

// Initialize an empty datasource
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);

// Override native filter predicate.
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.filterPredicate;

// Bootstrap the table config
this.buildTableConfig({});

let _defaultEmptyData: Array<any>;

/**
 * In the Builder > Canvas, we want to see one row of empty columns so they can be configured.
 * Otherwise, don't show a row of empty columns.
 */
const emptyRow = this.jsf.mode === 'builder' ? this.defaultEmptyData : [];

const formData = this.jsf?.data || {};
if (isDefined(formData[this.controlName])) {
  _defaultEmptyData = formData[this.controlName];

  // Don't default an empty row. Check if any of the columns have values.
  if (_defaultEmptyData?.length === 1) {
    let hasColumnValues = false;
    const firstRow = _defaultEmptyData[0];
    for (const column in firstRow) {
      if (column) {
        if (isDefined(firstRow[column])) {
          hasColumnValues = true;
        }
      }
    }
    _defaultEmptyData = hasColumnValues ? _defaultEmptyData : emptyRow;
  }
} else {
  _defaultEmptyData = emptyRow;
}

if (this.options.rowSelection) {
  _defaultEmptyData = this.defaultUndefinedSelection(_defaultEmptyData);
}

// _defaultEmptyData = this.defaultEmptyColumnData(_defaultEmptyData);

this.updateTableData(_defaultEmptyData);

// Initialize the table config and connect enabled table features: sort, pagination & filtering
this.updateTableConfig();

this.setFlexAttributes();

/**
 * NOTES
 * - If we have a 'datasourceEvent', should we still default data from the formControl? It will get overwritten when this returns data.
 * - Should the default formControl value be used instead of the data from the 'datasourceEvent'?
 * - How will this impact approver mode? Should we ignore in approver mode if form.data exists?
 */
if (this.options.hasOwnProperty('datasourceEvent')) {
  const event = this.options.datasourceEvent;
  const params = this.options.datasourceParams || [];
  this.getTableDatasource(event, params);
}

// Need to keep datasource and formControl data in sync
this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(value => value),
  distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => isEqual(a, b)),
  debounceTime(300)
).subscribe(value => {
  /**
   * NOTE
   * Setting `this.dataSource.data = value;` causes the table Inputs to be recreated.
   * This is causing Inputs to lose focus which is an issue for typing slower than the debounceTime.
   * Tried getting a copy of the document.activeElement, but it's gone by the time we can call .focus()
   * on it. So, instead we'll just delay the update until we have to. Which would be on sort or filter.
   * At that point any inline table edits have lost focus and its safe to update the table.
   */
  this.lastChangedValue = cloneDeep(this.formArrayValues);

  if (BOOL(this.options.footerRow)) {
    this.updateFooterTotals();
  }
});

/**
 * Listens for changes made by JsonSchemaFormComponent.updateData()
 */
this.syncComponentsSubscription = this.jsf.syncComponents.subscribe((value: SyncComponents) => {
  if (!value.targets.length || value.targets.includes(this.controlName)) {
    if (has(value, `data.${this.controlName}`)) {
      const newDatasource = value.data[this.controlName];
      const datasource = isUndefined(newDatasource) || !newDatasource.length
        ? this.jsf.mode === 'builder' ? this.defaultEmptyData : []
        : newDatasource;
      this.setTableDatasourceWith(datasource);
    }
  }
});

this.addRow();

this.jsf.registerComponentInit({ componentId: this.componentId, name: this.controlName });

// this._missingColumnConfigWarning();
```

}

Here is the `addRow()` method that's called at the end of the init to display the first row:

```
addRow(event?: MouseEvent) {
this.clearSort();
this.clearFilter(undefined);
const currentData = cloneDeep(this.formArrayValues);
currentData.push(this.emptyRowFromColumnDef); // Append new row to END of table
this.updateTableData(currentData);
if (this.paginationEnable && this.paginator) {
  // move table paging to last page to see newly added row. setTimeout helps avoid sync delay
  timer().subscribe(() => this.paginator.lastPage());
}
timer(1).subscribe(() => this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck());
event?.preventDefault();
```

}

Here is the trackByData method (attached to the parent ngFor ng-container):

```
 trackByData(index: any, item: any): any {
  const formArrayValueAtIndex = get(this.formArray, `value[${index}]`, item);
  item = formArrayValueAtIndex; // Override with fallback to orig item.
  const dataStr = `${index}` + (Object.keys(item).reduce((currentTerm: string, key: string) => {
    return `${currentTerm}${(item as { [key: string]: any })[key]}◬`;
  }, '').toLowerCase());

  return dataStr;
}
```

The `onCellChanged()` method which does not fire on a mat-autocomplete input until the value of the input is manually wiped and changed. Once I do that, I can get the data[column] element to update to reflect the last changed value of the input:

```
onCellChange($event, rowIndex, column): void {
  if (column !== SELECTION_COLUMN_NAME && column !== ACTIONS_COLUMN_NAME) {
    if (this.options.rowSelection && this.options.rowSelectionData) {
      let adjustedRow = this.pageEvent ? this.pageEvent.pageSize * this.pageEvent.pageIndex : 0;
      adjustedRow += rowIndex;
      const tableControls: FormArray = this.formControl as FormArray;
      const tableControlGroup: FormGroup = tableControls.at(adjustedRow) as FormGroup;
      const selectControl: FormControl = tableControlGroup.get(SELECTION_COLUMN_NAME) as FormControl;
      if (isDefined(selectControl)) {
        selectControl.setValue(true);
        console.log('cell change setvalue occurred');
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('this.data', this.data);
  console.log('this.lastChangedValue', this.lastChangedValue);

  // const currentData = cloneDeep(this.formArrayValues); // testing
  // this.updateTableData(currentData); // testing

  this.syncFormArrayToDataSource(); // this works to update the form

}
```

Here is the `syncFormArrayToDataSource()` method from the last line above:

```
/**
 * Should be called before every table sort or filter
 */
syncFormArrayToDataSource(): void {
  if (isDefined(this.lastChangedValue)) {
    // Set it...
    // this.dataSource.data = cloneDeep(this.lastChangedValue);
    this.data = cloneDeep(this.lastChangedValue);

    // Then forget it until its changed again by the FormArray.
    this.lastChangedValue = undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: provide a stackblitz link to help speed up the resolution of your issue

Comment: I don't have a stackblitz for this project. I believe the core issue is that the oncellchanged() is not firing when the onchange of the material input's mat-autocomplete occurs. Forcing an oncellchange (by manually clearing the input and blurrring out) allows it to fire and triggers the call to syncFormArrayToDataSource() which *does* cause the data to update and expected view update of the span to match the value chosen in the mat input